# Undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby 3.1 Rails 1.9.2 Absolute newb

Trouble begins when I try to edit the existing ad in application.

I get "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" error. Here is the information that might give clues as to what went wrong. I've spent a couple of hours trying to figure it out to no avail.

*Routes.rb*

```
match 'ads/:id/edit' => 'ads#edit'
match 'ads/:id/update' => 'ads#update'
match 'ads/' => 'ads#index'
match 'ads/new' => 'ads#new'
match 'ads/create' => 'ads#create
```

*Entries in controller*

```
def edit
  @ad=Ad.find(params[:id])
end

def update
        @ad=Ad.find(params[:id])
        @ad.update_attributes(params[:id])
        redirect_to "/ads/#{@ad.id}"
end
```

*View:*

```
<%= form_for(@ad,:url=>{:action=>'update'}) do |f| %>
<p><b>Name</b><br /><%= f.text_field :name %></p>
<p><b>Description</b><br /><%= f.text_area :description, rows: 10 %></p> 
<p><b>Price</b><br /><%= f.text_field :price %></p>
<p><b>Seller</b><br /><%= f.text_field :seller_id %></p>
<p><b>E-mail</b><br /><%= f.text_field :email %></p>
<p><b>Img url</b><br /><%= f.text_field :img_url %></p>
<p><%= f.submit "Update" %></p>
<% end %>
```

---

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but I recommend still using Ruby 1.8-style hashes (i.e. `:rows => 10`) instead of 1.9-style (`rows: 10`), unless you know that this application will always and forever be running in environments with Ruby 1.9.2. Otherwise, you'll have to go back and change the style of every hash in your application.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things:

@mu-is-too-short's example of an update method is correct. You should be sending a hash of attributes (`params[:ad]`) to the `@ad` object, rather than the parameter `params[:id]`.

Explicitly writing out routes like that could get very messy. You can replace everything you've written in your `routes.rb` file there with this:

```
resources :ads
```

This would give you the ability to use things like

```
redirect_to ad_path(@ad)
```

in place of

```
redirect_to "/ads/#{@ad.id}"
```

In addition, your form would be much easier to manage and less prone to error, because you could just say:

```
<%= form_for @ad do |f| %>
  <p><b>Name</b><br /><%= f.text_field :name %></p>
  <p><b>Description</b><br /><%= f.text_area :description, rows: 10 %></p> 
  <p><b>Price</b><br /><%= f.text_field :price %></p>
  <p><b>Seller</b><br /><%= f.text_field :seller_id %></p>
  <p><b>E-mail</b><br /><%= f.text_field :email %></p>
  <p><b>Img url</b><br /><%= f.text_field :img_url %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Update" %></p>
<% end %>
```

As an aside, I recommend studying up a little bit on HTML semantics. A form that looks more like this is easier to maintain and style, and is also more accessible:

```
<%= form_for @ad do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 10 %>
  </fieldset>

  <!-- etc -->

  <fieldset>
    <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

If you haven't already, I highly recommend reading through all of the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), especially the [guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: 1. Thanks a lot, lots of useful tips. Since I'm a complete newbe I don;t exactly understand why sending a hash of attributes (params[:ad]) to the @ad object wouldn't work. And most important - would you be able to give me an example of code that most likely will work in this case for update method? What should I use instead of this code?
@ad.update_attributes(params[:id])

Comment: 2. Silly question.
I thought that some of the code might lead to the error I mentioned. So I just commented out the whole "update" section in controllers code hoping that it will get me at least to the edit page - but still, I receive the same error when I click on 'edit' link and get to the Edit page.

Comment: 1. You *should* be sending a hash of attributes to `@ad`. Your current method sends a single integer: `params[:id]`, which is the value of the `id` column for `@ad` in your database. `params[:ad]` holds the form data. You should be using `@ad.update_attributes(params[:ad])`.

Comment: 2. Can you post the entire output of the error? Rails should be showing you where it's encountering the troublesome code. I would start by changing `routes.rb` as I suggested, as well as then just using `form_for @ad do |f|`.

Comment: 2. 
 [I would start by changing routes.rb] ***** Did that right away and it didn't help. I've also changed the html semantics to the one you suggested. I also used form_for @ad do |f| and I still got the same error.

Comment: 2. Entire error code
Showing c:/RailsInstaller/work/mebay/app/views/ads/edit.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for @ad do |f| %>
2:   <fieldset>
3:     <%= f.label :name %>
4:     <%= f.text_field :name %>
Rails.root: c:/RailsInstaller/work/mebay
app/views/ads/edit.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_ads_edit_html_erb__317645714_43786236'

Comment: 1. 
You should be using @ad.update_attributes(params[:ad]) *** Got it now, thanks. Changed to the suggested (params[:ad]) but still the same error.

Comment: Looks like `@ad` is nil for some reason. I have seen this happen before, but don't remember why. Everything you've posted here looks solid, so the issue must be somewhere else. Is the database migrated and set up properly? Are you sure that the ad you're editing exists?

Comment: The ad exists for sure, I have to bring the the ad page first (which shows correctly) and click the Edit link on that page.
The database is a small one - slite3 file that I downloaded from the book site and replaced my original development.sqlite3 file. The database is rather small, just 10 entries, so I can create the new one manually to see if it helps.

Comment: Think the problem could be with the link itself that leads to edit page - it looks like that - <a href="/ads/<%= @ad.id %>/edit">Edit</a>
****
I'm trying now to use the other format, but need a bit of help:
<%= link_to "Edit your post", ad_path %> - it stays on the same page, how do I tell it to go to @ad.id?

Comment: `ad_path(@ad)`. `ad_path` is a method that accepts an `@ad` object as its argument. What does the view you're linking from look like?

Comment: seems like a dead end - the view I'm linking from is ok - it shows ads in the web pages with no problem when called.

Comment: This should be pretty simple to find. If your source code is posted somewhere I could take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `update` controller method is confused. Passing an ID to `update_attributes` won't get you anywhere that you want to go, you want to pass some attributes to that method and those should be in `params[:ad]`, a bit of error handling might be nice too:

```
def update
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
    if(@ad.update_attributes(params[:ad]))
        # It worked, redirect to the show action.
    else
        # It didn't work, make them do it again.
    end
end
```

Comment: " Passing an ID to update_attributes won't get you anywhere that you want to go"


---- I'd appreciate if you could explain why it wouldn't get me anywhere? (The problem I'm facing is that I'm using the book I really like - Head First Rails - but it uses the previous version of rails. The example I mentioned is taken right from that book ( @ad.update_attributes(params[:id])) So I guess it's the version discrepancy thing that confuses it all)

Comment: @Elijah: `params[:id]` is an ID number but `update_attributes` wants a Hash of attribute names and their new values. You need an up-to-date book.

Comment: I highly recommend not using a book for Rails 2 if you're using Rails 3. There are lots of differences and incompatibilities, and you'll miss out on most of the things that make Rails 3 an improvement.

Comment: @ mu is too short:  I agree, the only reason I'm sticking to that book is that I haven't seen any other book that really explains things that clearly. I have a bunch of other books that I'm reading too - one of them is Agile Web Development for ruby 3.1. It's just I need some basics too. ((I'm a network admin with 12 years of experience, but the only thing that I did close to programming was a bit of linux scripting - so I need the book that touches that basics really thoroughly)